# Математическая библиотека выполнения произвольной арифметической функции с учётом деления на 0

Tags: php, математика, math

Можете подсказать, если ли математическая библиотека выполнения произвольной арифметической функции с учётом деления на 0.
Например, есть у меня строка, которая путём некоторого преобразования превращается в арифметическое выражение

```
"1 + 2 / 0";
```

Выполнение с помощью функции eval() данного выражения даст ошибку "Division by zero". Но мне нужно, чтобы такие участки "2 / 0" определялись и давали значение 0.
Это важно, т.к. у меня есть несколько сотен таких строк, которые генерируются на лету. Есть и строки, в которых много уровней вычисления с кавычками, когда данные сначала вычисляются в кавычках (с делением на 0), затем делятся на переменную (которая тоже может быть нулём) и т.д.
Ручной разбор таких строк для ручного перехвата таких мест я не смог написать - очень сложно.
Есть ли библиотеки, которые могут обойти корректно эту ошибку?
Пробовал следующие библиотеки:

- rodriados/mathr
- mossadal/math-parser
- fintara/calculator-php

Все они не подходят

Comment: А откуда у вас получились такие строки? Похоже на xy проблему.

Comment: В системе руками создаются различные правила вычисления некоторых параметров, например, "1 - $a / $b", где переменные $a и $b подставляются из текущих данных, вносимых извне. Причём эти значения могут быть любыми, в том числе и нулём. И 0 - это нормальное валидное значение

Comment: Более подробный пример "($a + $b / $c) / $d + $e * $f". Значения в переменные подставляются любые - от 0 до бесконечности (почти). В этом случае, если значения $c и/или $d равны 0, вся функция выдаст NAN (php 7.1), а мне надо чтобы оно выдало результат выражения "$e * $f"

Comment: @pavel, это верно. Разруха не в клозетах...